# Set the command line argument for sql file with \i in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am running the sql script for postgres.

Sql script(books.sql) is:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename AS TABLE booksback WITH NO DATA;

INSERT INTO tablename (SELECT * from booksback);

TRUNCATE TABLE books CASCADE;
```

I want to set the table name with command line argument.

I am running the script as:

```
postgres=# \i \books.sql;
```

I want to know how to set the pass the table name in sql file using \i option in postgres.

I have tried the -v option and :set as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible because `\i` takes only one parameter: the filename to be processed.

If you want to pass additional parameters you need to use psql command line arguments that you mentioned like `-v`.